# JS/ReactJS: How to get all input values of a table?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

This is an example table data:

```
const tableData = [
    ['one', 'two', 'three'],
    ['uno', 'dos', 'tres'],
    ['ichi', 'ni', 'san']
]
```

The data will be rendered like this:

```
render() {
    <Table>
        <Table.Body>
            {
                tableData.map((row, rowIndex) => {
                    return (
                        <Table.Row key={ rowIndex }>
                            {
                                row.map((cell, cellIndex) => {
                                    return (
                                        <Table.Cell key={ cellIndex }>
                                            <Input
                                                defaultValue={ cell }
                                                onChange={ this.tableChange }
                                            />
                                        </Table.Cell>
                                    )
                                })
                            }
                        </Table.Row>
                    )
                })
            }
        </Table.Body>
    </Table>
}
```

Now I need to get an updated dataset on `onChange` of an `Input` element.

```
tableChange(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value)
}
```

This is how I get the updated current element value. But I need to get the complete updated array - like the input array.

I would think of using the key values, but maybe I need some `data`-attributes?

Comment: Do you have control over the `Input` component? or is it a library?

Comment: I have complete control. I can change everything

Comment: then in the `Input` component you can add a prop like `index` that the actual position of the value,  `<Input defaultValue={ cell } onChange={ this.tableChange } index={cellIndex} />` and return it in your input click handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an example to cover your case, so let say we have the `Table` 
component which will just render all the code above

## Table

```
class Table extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      tableData: [
        ['one', 'two', 'three'],
        ['uno', 'dos', 'tres'],
        ['ichi', 'ni', 'san']
      ]
    };
  }

  renderRows() {
    const { tableData } = this.state;

    return tableData.map((cells, rowIndex) => (
      <tr key={ rowIndex }>
        {this.renderCells(cells, rowIndex)}
      </tr>
    ));
  }

  renderCells(cells, rowIndex) {
    return cells.map((cell, cellIndex) => (
      <td key={ cellIndex }>
        <Input
          cellIndex={cellIndex}
          rowIndex={rowIndex}
          defaultValue={cell}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
      </td>
    ));
  }

  onChange(event, cellIndex, rowIndex) {
    this.state.tableData[rowIndex][cellIndex] = event.target.value;
    const tableData = this.state.tableData;

    console.log('values:', event.target.value, cellIndex, rowIndex);
    console.log('tableData:', tableData);

    this.setState({ tableData });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <table>
        <tbody>
          {this.renderRows()}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}
```

## Input

```
function Input({ onChange, cellIndex, rowIndex, defaultValue }) {
  const onInputChange = event => {
    onChange(event, cellIndex, rowIndex);
  };

  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      value={defaultValue}
      onChange={onInputChange}
    />
  );
}
```

There is nothing wrong with passing the index of the elements.
As you can see in the `<Input />` component you can pass the reference of `rowIndex` and `cellIndex` so you the component knows which element of the array is being updated and then notify it to the parent when the `onChange` event is triggered.

Here is a working example of this, check it out: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/awjgKb?editors=0010